# How to get logcat output on PC from Google Arc Welder/Cordova app?

Tags: cordova, adb, google-chrome-arc

I am attempting to get `logcat` logs from a Cordova app running on Google Arc Welder.

I have tried the following sequence of steps:

1. Started the app from google arc welder
2. Start adb logcat with the command `adb logcat -d`
3. Enable output from chrome by typing `plugin.shell("logcat")` into the javascript console for my app.

After I type `plugin.shell("logcat")` the adb logcat window stops saying that it is waiting for devices and exits instead of printing logs.

I have also tried the `plugin.shell("logcat")` command ib the JS console window but don't get any android-specific logs there either.

What should I do differently in order to be able to do logs from my Android app in Google Arc Welder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

by setting the extra metadata "stderrLog" level to "V" and then redeploying the app with ARC Welder will show the logcat output when you issue the command plugin.shell('logcat') in the JS console.
On Chrome OS it will also show the logging in file:///var/log/ui/ui.LATEST

Comment: Is that inside Arc Welder or somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, that's inside ARC Welder. After you've added your apk, at the bottom of the screen there is a field named "Additional Metadata". In this field you can add metadata in JSON format. For the logging add this: {"stderrLog": "V"}

Comment: Cool thanks. Is there somewhere where that is documented so I could play with log levels?

Comment: No, not by my knowledge. There used to be a public Google docs link but that has been replaced by https://developer.chrome.com/apps/getstarted_arc#bestpractices. Unfortunately this doesn't contain the ARC Welder metadata description. I found about it inside the js files from ARC itself https://console.developers.google.com/storage/browser/arc-sdk/